# Erro ao abrir o android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quando abro meu android studio ele carrega o Gradle e em seguida mostra a mensagem:

```
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

Ja rodei, atualizei mexi em configuraçao, mudei pra versão 2.0 do AS e o erro continua. Ja mudei a versao do googleservices e nada.. ja não sei mais o que fazer, alguem pode me ajudarw`

Comment: O problema é que não existe ou o arquivo `google-services.json`, que configura todos os serviços que utiliza do google play services está no local errado. Caso tenha, coloque o arquivo na raiz do módulo principal ou crie um nesse site: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: Verifique se no build.gadle  do seu android se não em alguma biblioteca que o android não esteja aceitando..